# Tomcat server serving concurrent requests

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I have a following problem with Tomcat when serving concurrent request:

I created a mock web service, I use Thread.sleep(time) to define execution time of the mock service. I deployed this service to Tomcat.

I created a client to send multiple requests (50 requests) to the service in concurrently.

When I set the execution time to a small number (e.g. 2000 milliseconds), 50 requests are successfully returned. However, when I set the execution  time to a bigger number (e.g. 5000 milliseconds), some requests are fail. The bigger of the execution time causes larger number of failures.

I have been playing around with thread pool configuration of Tomcat, but no help so far. My current configuration for my Tomcat connector is as follows:

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" 
            port="8080" 
            protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
            connectionTimeout="2000000" 
            acceptCount="50" 
            redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Could someone suggest me a solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, as you have sufficient concurrent threads (`maxThreads=150`) to handle 50 requests simultaneously. The Executor can however be shared with other connectors so there's a slight possibility that the threads are used elsewhere?
More likely I would say this should work and perhaps the configuration above is not active yet. If you changed this from within Eclipse, did you do a "publish" (in the server view, right-click on the tomcat server and select 'publish`)? Then restart tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I also think this is strange. I already checked that the configuration is active.
The thing is that when i set Thread.sleep(time) with time = 2000, it works correctly, but when time = 5000 then some requests are fail.

Comment: A longer sleep means the threads are occupied longer thus they are inable to serve other requests, probably causing them to time out. That could not happen if you actually had 50 threads. So by the looks of it, you have less threads OR more than 150 parallel requests. Perhaps can you post the whole server.xml? And how are you launching the requests?

Comment: Please see the whole server.xml here: [server.xml](https://github.com/trangmx/phdproject/blob/master/Tomcat/conf/server.xml). 
I configure my application to send only 50 requests in parallel, you can see the access log on the server in this log file: [access log](https://github.com/trangmx/phdproject/blob/master/Tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2015-09-11.txt)

Comment: access.log shows that several requests actually get HTTP status code 500. This should give some stack traces in one or another log file. Can you show these?

Comment: Here is [catalina log](https://github.com/trangmx/phdproject/blob/master/Tomcat/logs/catalina.2015-09-11.log). I could not find errors in here.

Comment: maybe in `localhost.*` ?

Comment: There are also no errors in [localhost.*](https://github.com/trangmx/phdproject/blob/master/Tomcat/logs/localhost.2015-09-11.log)